# KnockOut Validation not using localization settings when using showAllMessages()

Tags: asp.net, validation, knockout.js, locale, knockout-validation

I´m using KnockOut Validation to validate a Form ClientSide. Everything is working perfect except when i call the Method `showAllMessages(true)`, it shows all messages in English, ignoring the locale settings. My code looks like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMaster" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="js/bootstrap.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="js/knockout-3.3.0.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="js/knockout.validation.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="js/es-ES.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="js/App/_run.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="js/App/App.DataModel.js"/>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="js/App/App.ViewModel.js"/>
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>

ko.validation.locale("es-es");
ko.validation.init({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: true,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    errorElementClass: "has-error",
    errorMessageClass: "help-block",
    decorateInputElement: true
}, true);

self.saveUser = function () {
    var errors = ko.validation.group(self, { deep: true });
    if (errors().length === 0) {
        var user = ko.toJSON(self);
        dataModel.putUser(user)
            .done(function(result) {
                alert("Se guardó el usuario");
            })
            .fail(self.onUserCreationError);
    } else {
        errors.showAllMessages(true);
    }
}
```

When i do `saveUser()` it validates correctly, but all error messages look like "`This field is required`" instead of "`Este campo es requerido`" as it should be since i'm using `es-es` locale

How do i get it to use the locale in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went trough the `ko.validation.js` file and found those messages are directly in the file and the responses are not referencing the `locale.js` messages. A quick fix, was to change those messages from english to the `locale.js` one manually or doing something like:

```
kv.rules = {};
kv.rules['required'] = {
    validator: function (val, required) {
        var testVal;

        if (val === undefined || val === null) {
            return !required;
        }

        testVal = val;
        if (typeof (val) === 'string') {
            if (String.prototype.trim) {
                testVal = val.trim();
            }
            else {
                testVal = val.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');


    }
    }

    if (!required) {// if they passed: { required: false }, then don't require this
        return true;
    }

    return ((testVal + '').length > 0);
},
message: 'Este campo es obligatorio.'
};
```